# Hidden files won't stay hidden in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, files, directory

Whenever I open my files, my hidden files show up. I can hide them but when I open up my files again, they're showing again. How do I make the hidden files invisible permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have set the option *Show hidden and backup files* in the *Edit* -> *Prefererences*. Just clear the checkbox and the hidden files will stay hidden after you re-open the file manager.

Answer (score 1):

Or if that solution doesn't work because you are affected by bug 1171852, then try this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1171852/comments/14

It was the only of many options that worked for me without installing additional tools (like dconf)

Comment: For me none, including "dconf > org > gnome > nautilus > preferences" worked; this was the only cure for what might be a bug that has re-emerged in Ubuntu 15.04 (Nautilus 3.14.2).